# Прокрутка и fastapi

Tags: python, прокрутка, fastapi

Всем привет. Прошу помощи, пожалуйста.
Пытаюсь разобраться  с fastapi, опыта немного.
Есть задача.  Реализовать приложение, кот будет выводить след страницу при прокрутке до конца страницы, прелоадер, дальше новые элементы в конец добавлять. Уже просмотренные запоминать(пока не понимаю как реализовать).
Это учебная задача для освоения fastapi.
У меня есть модели,  схемы(для педантика) , дБ через алхимию, написал пагинацию, которая будет рендерить в шаблон данные, используя jinja
Во фронте ничего не знвю(кроме базовых вещей).
Подскажите,  в каком направлении идти и думать.
Вот ест данные из бд,  есть вьюха, кот обрабатывает эти данные.  Мне надо,  чтобы фронт как-то  дергал мою пагинацию. Погуглил всякое про прокрутку, но яснее не стало(. Не понимаю,  пока,  как это реализовать.
Буду благодарен  за ваши идеи.

Comment: Очень легко сказать "я попробовал, не получилось", не убедительно, не верю:) По запросу на этом сайте ["бесконечный скролл"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=бесконечный+скролл) можно найти множество потенциальных дубликатов. Например, какой-то [такой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/640791/infinte-scroll-для-динамически-добавляемых-данных) устроил бы?

Comment: во-первых, я уже сделал, с мучениями, но сделал, во-вторых, смысл врать, если я просил идеи, а не код. в-третьих, я писал, что вопрос не с бесконечном скоролле, а в том, как мне связать бэк на фастапи с фронтом, мне это было не очевидно. Поэтому, ваше недоверие необоснованно.

Comment: Во-первых смысла врать много, люди разные бывают, поверьте, мы же всего не знаем о вашем пути:) Во-вторых [руководствуясь правилами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) и опытом пребывания на сайте, я считаю, что вопросы в духе "не знаю, как начать вот с этим, помогите идеями" - мало полезны и крайне неоднозначно воспринимаются сообществом. В-третьих, по ссылке - как раз идеи, которые могут быть полезны. В-четвертых, поздравляю с победой, если так, то опубликуйте, пожалуйста, решение в качестве ответа и отметье его, как верный. Другим будет полезно, однозначно.